# Is it possible to provide a custom "stateToPropagate" when extending the Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass class?

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom apex class that extends the base [Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm). I am attempting to call the initiate method of this class from a custom LWC. The problem that I am running into is that the "state" variable, which is inputed into the "initiate" method by default, is causing problems.

When i remove the "state" variable i get the error :
`Remote_Error: The remote service returned an error`

When i put a dummy value for the "state" variable I get the error :
`No_Oauth_State: State was not valid`

To note :

- the Auth.Provider, Named Cred, and External Cred records were all created via the tooling API
- I've tried initiating the Authorization from both the External Credential & calling the `initiate` method via apex, both have the same result using the 3 methods below

I am trying to figure out how to enable a custom state when initiating the custom AuthProvider from within an apex class.

for context here is an example of my request from apex (the user is redirected to the result of that initiate method callout) :

```
 // Get the MDT record information
AuthCredential__mdt authCredentialMDT = [SELECT Id, Client_Id__c, Auth_URL__c, Scope__c, Redirect_URI__c FROM AuthCredential__mdt WHERE DeveloperName =:authProviderDeveloperName];
Map<String, String> stringMap = new Map<String, String>();
Map<String, Object> objectMap = (Map<String, Object>)(JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(authCredentialMDT)));
for(String key : objectMap.keySet()) {stringMap.put(key, String.valueOf(objectMap.get(key)));}

 // Get the authorization page URL
CustomAuthProvider authMethod = new CustomAuthProvider();
PageReference newPage = authMethod.initiate(stringMap, 'test');
result = newPage.getUrl();
```

I've tried :

1. removing the "state" variable from my authorization URL
2. adding a dummy "stage" variable, such as "test" to my auth URL
3. including the default "state" variable when launching the authorization from the Principle on the External Credential page.

Comment: This question should be in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

So the state cant be customized. But to initiate the flow, direct your user to the "linkKickoffUrl" variable listed on the AuthProvider record.

Directing the user to that URL will call the `initiate` method and provide a pre-configured state, which launches the auth flow.

ALSO
check to see if your authentication provider is using Open ID... if it is, then don't bother with the custom auth. provider

Comment: If the Open ID provider deprecated Consumer Key, you can't use the standard auth. provider